# How can I build a responsive navbar on blogger.com that becomes a drop-down-menu, if the screen is too small?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, blogger

First of all: I'm from Germany, so I'm sorry for my bad English... I hope, you'll understand everything!

I am an almost 16-year-old student who is really interested in coding. Next year I'm going to study computer science at the university.
So lately I've begun to learn something about HTML and CSS. To use my new knowledge, I created a "fake-/test-blog" on Blogger.com (from Google).

I found a german tutorial how to write an own template, but this instruction wasn't one for a responsive design. So I tried and tried and achieved success - except from one thing...

The reason, why I am here now, is that I want to create a menu in the navbar, which becomes/turns into a kind of drop-down-menu, if the screen is too small to show the whole menu in line (e.g. on a smarthpone or tablet or a 4:3-screen etc.).

I searched on the internet for a long time, but I found no useful information there. Every instruction I found was with JavaScript, but I need a code that works only with HTML and CSS...

So maybe someone can help me here with links, codes etc. I hope that my problem is understandable and especially solvable!

Thanks in advance!

Ninjo

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) which is a mobile-first framework ideal for makijng something like a responsive navbar.

You could also take a look at [pure css](http://purecss.io/) which is another nifty framework for achieving this

Also: 
As mentioned by Samus Hands you can take a look at [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Good luck with the coding & the education

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With CSS media queries you can know if the screen is too long/small, a exemple using @media screen and (max-width: (or min)...):

```
@media screen and (max-width:200px){
  .element-class{display:block}
/* These definitions applies to screens with width 0px to 200px; */
}

@media screen and (min-width:201px){
  .element-class{display:block}
/* These definitions applies to screens with width 201px or above; */
}
```

It's good to not depend of the javascript that may be unable in some clients browser, then CSS is very useful for your blogs/websites.

Know the CSS pseudo-classes too, but Javascript also is a good language to learn and sometime you may need it.